# Which closed 3-manifolds can be embedded in $R^4$?

Tags: 3-manifolds

I wonder which closed orientable 3-manifolds can be embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ and which in $\mathbb R^5$. Is there a way to determine whether given closed 3-manifold, obtained, say by Dehn surgery on knot, can be embedded into $R^4$ ?

Is the answer known for spherical 3-manifolds (finite fundamental group) ?

I am mainly interested in topological properties of manifolds. The known answers for PL or smooth embedding are of value as well for me. I appreciate any kind of answer. I am not interested in such peculiarities as exotic $R^4$.

Comment: They all embed in $R^5$ (C.T.C. Wall, BAMS 1956), but the question of embedding in $R^4$ seems a hard one. See http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/which_compact_boundaryless_3_manifolds_embed_smoothly_in_the_4_sphere

Comment: related question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/219313/1345 see also http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2346

Comment: Do you mean smooth or PL embeddings, or just topological embeddings?

Comment: This latter question is maybe a question to be asked on math.stackexchange, rather than in a comment here.

Comment: OK. I admit my main question could be naive. I expect some kind of analogy to the surfaces but clearly there is no such analogy. I expect to make some kind of order in set of all 3-manifolds. I saw that fundamental group might be used for that purpose. I tried detection by embedding in $R^4$. Have someone tried kind of Morse function $f$ on $R^4$ which should return 3-manifolds as $f^-1(p)$ ?

Comment: Note that every closed orientable 3-manifold immerses into $\mathbb{R}^4$. This follows from Hirsch-Smale. So there are no "easy" obstructions (e.g. characteristic classes) to embedding.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: in a sense there is something easier than characteristic classes.  Compute the torsion subgroup of $H_1$, and check that for each prime power $p^k$ the subgroup $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ occurs an even number of times in the prime-power direct-sum factorization of the torsion subgroup.

Answer (score 12):

There is an analogy to surfaces in a sense.  For 3-manifolds that fibre over surfaces there is a complete answer.  For a variety of Seifert-fibred manifolds there are complete answers -- but not all.  For example, Seifert-fibred homology spheres are still problematic.   The preprint that Ian linked to in his comments has much more results of this kind in it.

At present, in summary:

1. We likely do not have a complete set of invariants that obstruct embedding into $\mathbb R^4$.
2. We appear to be far from knowing all the "natural" constructions of embeddings of 3-manifolds into $\mathbb R^4$ for the manifolds that are known to embed.

It is quite possible there are elements of formal logic obstructing both 1 and 2.

For example, if a compact boundaryless connected 3-manifold embeds in $S^4$ it separates it into two components.  It is possible that one or even both of these components has a fundamental group with an unsolvable word problem.  This would restrict the kinds of techniques one could use for creating obstructions in (1).

edit: I see Agol and Freedman's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2391) on this topic as connected to this last concern.  2-manifolds in $S^3$ have the Fox re-embedding theorem.  So you could hope for some nice re-embedding theorems for $3$-manifolds in $S^4$.  You shouldn't expect **too nice** a re-embedding theorem in $S^4$, since the tool that makes Fox's theorem work is Dehn's lemma, and the analogies to Dehn's lemma in 4-manifold theory are generally not true.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers ! I am reading your paper now suggested by Ian Agol. At my present knowledge it is a mistery why Poincare homology sphere has tame topological embedding in $S^4$ but it does not have smooth embedding in $S^4$.

Comment: @MarekMitros: you are not alone.  In principle there is a semi-constructive embedding but it is not easy to visualize.  This is a result of Mike Freedman's.  The embedding construction involves a type of infinite handle adjunctions.  So the fact that you have a tubular neighbourhood is not obvious at all.

Answer (score 10):

Results on the subject seem spotty, but the last of them seems to be:

```
MR3271270 Reviewed 
Donald, Andrew(4-GLAS-SMS)
Embedding Seifert manifolds in S4. (English summary) 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 367 (2015), no. 1, 559–595.
```

Comment: Scott Morrison can't be notified this way since he did not participate in this thread. However, I'll alert him to your comment.

Comment: After you search, click on your chosen result, then click the "Insert citation" button down in the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: @ScottMorrison I could not find such a button, probably a browser issue...

Comment: Let's sort this out via email.